# Error: RuntimeError: file <maya console> line 1: Unable to create/find dependency node

Tags: python, plugins, maya

I get this problem while running tdl_FFDA node from 3DeepLearner.

Comment: Pierre, could you please provide a little bit more information about what you have tried, show some code. Is this a plugin or only python code?

Comment: hi! i'm using a custom deformer wriiten in python called 'tdl_FFDA' (https://3deeplearner.com/siggraph-01/) and i got an error when i try to launch it using 'cmds.deformer('type='tdl_FFDA'')' with a mesh selected as target

Comment: Are you sure that the plugin loaded correctly?

Comment: good idea, i will try to load it step by step to see if i gte an issue.